# Why are special characters garbled for some webpages when downloaded from an AWS s3 website?

Tags: html, amazon-s3

We have a browser extension that allows users to upload html webpages and assets to s3, which generally works well.  The one issue we have is that special characters, -, ', " etc. are garbled for some webpages.  For example, a dash '-' will show up as  â€“  in the browser source and displayed that way.  The dash is there as '-' in the s3 html.  This only occurs in some webpages we upload, including questions from stack overflow (the dash before a username in a comment).  The only metadata for the s3 html file is Content-type: text/html.  Manually setting the character encoding type to auto-detect fixes it temporarily, but we can't figure out how to permanently fix this and could use some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly likely because your hyphens are actually Unicode UTF-8 em or en dashes and the quote characters are Unicode curved quotes rather than the basic ASCII ones. For example the dashes in StackOverflow questions appear to be em dashes.

You need to tell the browser the correct encoding as it is trying to guess and getting it wrong. There are a couple of ways to this:

1. When you are uploading the file you can set the S3 Content-Type metadata attribute for the file to say, `text/html;charset=UTF-8`. This will depend on the software you use to upload. This attribute can also be set in the AWS console but this would be tedious if there a lot of files.
2. You can embed the encoding in the document itself as described [here](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations). For example you could add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `head` of the document and the browser should use that to decide the encoding.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  We needed to pass the Content-type so it includes text/html;charset=UTF=8, otherwise s3 just sets it to "text/html".